# Passing array in request body in node express js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, post, mongoose

I have an array that I would like to pass in my request body for a POST request. If successful, a new document should be inserted into MongoDB. Here is my code so far:

```
app.post(`/api/add`, async (req, res) => {
    collection.create( {  'id': req.body.id, 
                        'name': req.body.name, 
                        'date': req.body.date,
                        'groups': [
                            { 'id': req.body.groups.id, 'title': req.body.groups.title, 'teamMemberIds': [ req.body.groups.teamMemberIds] }]
                    }, 
    (err, result ) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error', err)
        } else {
            console.log('updated', result);
            res.status(200).send(result);
        }
    })
});
```

I am sending the request body in postman like so:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Saved Team 1",
    "date": "1/1/20",
    "groups": [
        {"id": "group-1", "title": "test saved group 1", "teamMemberIds": ["bpumper", "jdoe"] },
        {"id": "group-2", "title": "test saved group 2", "teamMemberIds": ["bsimmons", "ljames"] },
    ]
}
```

Here is my mongoose schema:

```
const savedTeamSchema = new Schema({
    id: String,
    name: String,
    date: String,
    groups: [{ id: String, title: String, teamMemberIds: [String]}]
})
```

However, after the request is executed, this is the document that gets inserted into the collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eed13b216b4836f406b6f63"),
    "id" : "1",
    "name" : "Saved Team 1",
    "date" : "1/1/20",
    "groups" : [ 
        {
            "teamMemberIds" : [ 
                null
            ],
            "_id" : ObjectId("5eed13b216b4836f406b6f64")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I cant figure out how to get the group object to get added into the `groups` array. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 { 'id': req.body.groups.id, 'title': req.body.groups.title, 'teamMemberIds': [ req.body.groups.teamMemberIds] }]
```

You cannot access fields of array's elements like this: `req.body.groups.id`, `req.body.groups.title` and `req.body.groups.teamMemberIDs`. In order to get the fields in the nested array you would have to do something like this `req.body.groups[index].id`.

But doing all of that is not necessary, since your req.body and mongoose schema are the same you can simply pass in the whole `req.body.groups` into `groups` like shown below.

```
app.post(`/api/add`, async (req, res) => {
    collection.create( {  'id': req.body.id, 
                        'name': req.body.name, 
                        'date': req.body.date,
                        'groups': req.body.groups //change this line of code.
                    }, 
    (err, result ) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error', err)
        } else {
            console.log('updated', result);
            res.status(200).send(result);
        }
    })
});
```

Or even better you could just add the entire `req.body` to `collection.create()`

```
app.post(`/api/add`, async (req, res) => {
    collection.create(req.body, 
    (err, result ) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error', err)
        } else {
            console.log('updated', result);
            res.status(200).send(result);
        }
    })
});
```

In case when your `req.body` and mongoose schema have different formats, then for the array parts you can use the array method `map` to change the array format prior to document creation.